# Trying to set up a variable length dropdown menu using php and pulling values from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 
    $exList = "select * from $exerciseTable";
    if($stmt = $conn->prepare($exList))
    {
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($id,$name);

        while ($stmt->fetch())
        {

            echo "<option value=$id>$name</option>";
        }
    }


?>
```

I'm trying to make a dropdown list that pulls values from a mySql table that can be added to in another location. When I add values to the list it increases the number of options for the drop down menu, However no text is displayed it is just empty slots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to explicitly specify the columns that need to be selected `id, name` and later on bound, because `*` selects all columns, so there is no way MySQLi to know to which columns to bind `id` and `name`.

```
$exList = "select id, name from $exerciseTable";
```

Then it will work.

For more information of the usage of binding results, you can check the [documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php).

Comment: @dlrdlrdlr if answer worked for you then accept it!!

Comment: Sorry there is a timer, I had to wait several minutes before it would let me click accept

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
        $exList = "select * from $exerciseTable";
        if($stmt = $conn->prepare($exList))
        {
            $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($id,$name);

        while ($stmt->fetch())
        {

            echo "<option value='".$id."'>$name</option>";
        }
    }


?>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: the $id variable was not enclosed in quotes, so its value was not echoed

Comment: so add it to your answer, so that people that read it in the future know's it

Comment: Didn't change anything noticeable.

Comment: @Manashvibirla Nope you can get the value if there's no space within values

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="DROPDOWN_NAME">
<?php 
    $exList = "select `id`, `name` from $exerciseTable";
    if($stmt = $conn->prepare($exList))
    {
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($id,$name);

        while ($stmt->fetch())
        {

            echo "<option value='$id'>$name</option>";
        }
    }


?>
</select>
```